# Choosing time_step for LSTM

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to reshape my input for my LSTM Network.
I have a training data of train_x (20214000 columns x 9 rows) and train_y (20214000 columns x 1 row).

How do I reshape my train_x such that I can feed it into my RNN?

I have 9 features so it would be something like:

`train_x.reshape(?,?,9)` and 
`train_y.reshape(?,?,1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays input into the LSTM have shape: `(N_SAMPLES, SEQUENCE_LENGTH, N_FEATURES)`.

Comment: How do I choose seq_length and n_samples?

Comment: what do the columns represent? I'm not sure how to answer without knowing what you are using the LSTM for

Comment: How would they effect what dimensions I use? Wouldn't any combination of samples and length be alright? The x train consists of features of building data. Like the floor area, weather, time of the year, etc,